# What is the natural JSF way to inplement this?

Tags: jsf-2

I am learning JSF2 and confused with folowing problem. I need to implement some kind of form in which I can supply variable number of marks.
Say, there is a group in which there is a students. Students learn some subject and get marks. In different groups can be from 10 to 30 students.
Form should contain a list of students with mark field for each student.
I see a few problems:

1. How can I render form with variable number of fields?
2. How can I pass marks to the managedBean?
3. How can I differ one student from another?

UPDATE
Explanations about data model.
There are folowing Entity-classess: `Person`, `StudyCard`, `StudyGroup`, `Subject` and `MonthMark`. `Person` represents fields, that are constant for some person (name, birthdate and so on). `StudyCard` represents something like personal card. It has many fields inclusing relation to the `Person` (`@ManyToOne`) and `StudyGroup` (`@ManyToOne`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
public class StudyCard implements Serializable {

. . . // fields

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "crd_grpcode")
private StudyGroup group;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "crd_psncode", nullable = false)
private Person person;

. . . //getters, setters 
}
```

`StudyGroup` is a group representation. `Subject` - it's representation for subject for which students will get the marks.
`MonthMark` - it's a representation of mark for student for subject. t will contain month, year, subject, studyCard and mark:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "monthmarks")
public class MonthMark implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "mmk_pcode")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "mmk_month", nullable = false)
  private int month;

  @Column(name = "mmk_year", nullable = false)
  private int year;

  @Column(name = "mmk_mark", nullable = false)
  private int mark;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mmk_subcode")
  private Subject subject;

  @Transient
  private int subjectCode;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mmk_psncode")
  private Person person;

  @Transient
  private int personCode;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mmk_crdcode")
  private StudyCard card;

  @Transient
  private int cardCode;

  . . . // getters, setters, etc
}
```

In the ManagedBean, I think, there will be one StudyGroup object, one Subject object and, I think, List.

Approximate xhtml layout, I think, will be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

  <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="groupId" value="#{monthMarksMB.groupCode}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{monthMarksMB.preparePage()}" />
  </f:metadata>  

  <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
      <h2>Marks for a month</h2>
      <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Subject" /><br />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{monthMarksMB.subjectCode}"
                           valueChangeListener="#{monthMarksMB.changeSubject}">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="---select subject---" itemValue="0" />
          <f:selectItems value="#{monthMarksMB.subjectsForGroup}" var="sub" 
                           itemLabel="#{sub.name}" itemValue="#{sub.id}" />
          <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form" render="@form globalMessages" />
        </h:selectOneMenu><p />
        <h:outputText value="Year" /><br />
        <h:inputText value="#{monthMarksMB.year}" class="textEdit" /><p />
        <h:outputText value="Month" /><br />
        <h:inputText value="#{monthMarksMB.month}" class="textEdit" /><p />

        <!-- And now I confused: how implement list of persons and marks?
        something like
        <ui:repeat ...>
          <h:outputText value="person fullname" />
          <h:inputText value="what should be here?" /><br />
        </ui:repeat> 
        -->

        <div class="buttons">
          <h:commandButton value="Сохранить" action="#{monthMarksMB.save()}" />
          <h:commandButton value="Отменить" action="#{monthMarksMB.cancel()}" />
        </div>
      </h:form>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

In this form there will be only one `MonthMark` for each person. Selection of the `Subject` in the menu will cause updating list of `MonthMarks`. If the marks already exists - I want it to be displayed to correct it. If there is no `MonthMarks` yet, should be an empty fields for input marks to save.

So, I asking for JSF guru help. What is the JSF natural way for this implementation?
Best regards.

Comment: It's due to all the ambiguity in your question hard to propose how the view should look like without knowing the exact (Java code) structure of the (data) model. So, start showing the model.

Comment: It's a good question. If I have variable number of students - how do I represent it in the managedBean? By the list? Since I use JPA, JPQL query returns me a List or Set. Is it possible to create form with variable fields for values in Set or List? I never seen souch examples.

Comment: I want to answer it, but I can't without knowing the exact model. E.g. is it a `List<Group>` of which `Group` class has in turn a `List<Student>`? Etc. This is just to exclude the ambiguity, otherwise I would only waste time on posting an answer which after all doesn't fit your actual model at all. The (DB) model design is in turn unrelated to JSF, so you surely should already have figured out it (if not, then you should have taken a step back and work on that first). I'll remove the downvote and the "Question is too broad" close vote once you edit the question to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: So, you have a `StudyGroup` which in turn has a one-to-many to `List<StudyCard>`. The remainder is still not exactly clear. Does `StudyGroup` have an one-to-one to `Subject`? (if not, where exactly is it linked and/or why exactly is it separately assigned in the controller?). Does `StudyCard` have a many-to-one to `Person`? And, does `StudyCard` have a one-to-many to `List<Mark>`? In any case, it will likely boil down to using a nested `<ui:repeat>` and/or `<h:dataTable>` of which the inner one has "Add" and "Remove" buttons for adding/removing `Mark`s.

Comment: I add mo explanations and some kind of xhtml layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have tried and seems like it's work. I made some simple test xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <title>JSF incubator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{testMB.edit}">
      <h2>Edit marks</h2>
      <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{testMB.subjectCode}" valueChangeListener="#{testMB.changeSubject}">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="---Select---" itemValue="0" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Computer skills" itemValue="1" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Phylosofy" itemValue="2" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Foreign languages" itemValue="3" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mathematics" itemValue="4" />
          <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <p>
        <ui:repeat value="#{testMB.marks}" var="mark">
          <h:outputText value="#{mark.person} " />
          <h:inputText value="#{mark.mark}" /><br />
        </ui:repeat>
        </p>
        <p>
          <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{testMB.save()}" />
        </p>
      </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not testMB.edit}">
      <h2>Show marks</h2>
        <p>
        <ui:repeat value="#{testMB.marks}" var="mark">
          <h:outputText value="#{mark.person} " />
          <h:outputText value="#{mark.mark}" /><br />
        </ui:repeat>
        </p>
      <h:form>
        <p>
          <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{testMB.change()}" />
        </p>
      </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

and TestMB managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testMB")
@ViewScoped
public class TestMB {

  private int subjectCode;
  private List<Mark> marks;
  private boolean edit;

  @PostConstruct
  private void initData() {
    edit = true;
  }

  public void save() {
    edit = false;
  }

  public void change() {
    edit = true;
  }

  public void changeSubject(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    try {
      int code = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
      if (code > 0) {
        marks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          marks.add(new Mark(0, code, "Person" + i));
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      addMessage("somethind wrong!");
    }
  }

  public List<Mark> getMarks() {
    return marks;
  }

  public int getSubjectCode() {
    return subjectCode;
  }

  public void setSubjectCode(int subjectCode) {
    this.subjectCode = subjectCode;
  }

  public boolean isEdit() {
    return edit;
  }
}
```

It was simpler, than I think. I hope, I understand how implement this on real deta.
Thanks for wasting your time.